# Check the firmware which a module needs

Tags: kernel-modules

in http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2242147&page=2,

> The driver requires firmware:
>
> ```
> $ modinfo iwlwifi
> filename:       /home/chili/Downloads/backports-3.16-1/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
> version:        backported from Linux (v3.16-0-g19583ca) using backports v3.16-1-0-g87df966
> license:        GPL
> author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
> version:        in-tree:d
> description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
> firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
> firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
> firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
> firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
> firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
> firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
> firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
> firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
> firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
> firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
> firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
> firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
> firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
> firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode
> firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode
> firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-8.ucode
> ```
>
> If your linux-firmware package is fully updated, you probably have it;
>   check: Code:
>
> ```
> $ ls /lib/firmware | grep 7260
> iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
> iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode
> iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode
> ```

The first command shows what firmware the module depends on. There are a number of such firmware

Then why in the second command, only check  firmware containing `7260` in filename? What about other firmware?

Does it also list the firmware not used by the module, such as `iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode` and `iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode`?

Comment: Since the title of the forum message you cited was `Ubuntu 14.04 reports no wireless card with Intel Wireless 7260`, it makes sense that an answer for it would be looking only for 7260 firmware.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Answers should be posted as answers.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks. How can I check if all the firmware  needed by `iwlwifi` are installed, instead of checking one by one by second command?

Comment: @Tim I don't know the answer to that part of your question.

Comment: @Mark:  to check if a firmware is installed, is the same to find if there is a file with the name under `/lib/firmware`?

Comment: @Tim I don't know. If you grep for `firmware` in `/var/log/syslog`, do you see any lines referring to iwlwifi firmware being requested and successfully loaded?

Comment: @Mark: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196031/how-to-find-information-about-a-firmware-and-install-it