# How to find information about a firmware and install it?

Tags: firmware

1. How can we find out information about a firmware, such as whether it
   is installed, and if installed, its version?

   if the firmware is installed, how can we find out its version and if
   it is outdated?

   If the firmware is not installed, how can we install it from where?

   For example,  my `lshw -C network` says `driver=iwlwifi 
   driverversion=3.16.0-34-generic  firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692`. 
   But my module `iwlwifi` depends on the following firmwares:

   ```
   $ modinfo iwlwifi
   filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
   license:        GPL
   author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
   version:        in-tree:
   description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
   firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
   firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
   firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
   firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
   firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
   firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
   firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
   firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
   firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
   firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
   firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
   firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
   firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
   firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode
   firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode
   firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-8.ucode
   srcversion:     93D664267873827B22C4309
   ```

   What is the version of my firmware, `8.83.5.1 build 33692`, or
   `8000-8` or some other number in the firmware names listed by
   `modinfo iwlwifi`?
2. I followed [Mark's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196021/check-the-firmware-which-a-module-needs?noredirect=1#comment328606_196021):

   ```
   $ grep firmware /var/log/syslog
   Apr 13 08:55:39 ocean kernel: [39341.818595] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 8.83.5.1 build 33692
   Apr 13 08:55:54 ocean kernel: [39357.100042] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
   Apr 13 08:56:09 ocean kernel: [39372.448055] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
   Apr 13 08:56:25 ocean kernel: [39387.640078] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
   Apr 13 08:57:06 ocean kernel: [39429.560058] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
   Apr 13 08:57:22 ocean kernel: [39444.744048] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
   Apr 13 08:57:37 ocean kernel: [39460.560055] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
   Apr 13 08:57:53 ocean kernel: [39475.752032] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
   Apr 13 08:58:18 ocean kernel: [39500.944045] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
   Apr 13 08:58:33 ocean kernel: [39516.484054] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
   Apr 13 08:58:49 ocean kernel: [39531.640046] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
   Apr 13 08:59:47 ocean kernel: [39589.852052] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
   Apr 13 09:00:02 ocean kernel: [39605.004072] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
   Apr 13 09:00:18 ocean kernel: [39620.780054] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
   Apr 13 09:00:33 ocean kernel: [39635.960060] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
   Apr 13 09:00:58 ocean kernel: [39661.160053] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
   Apr 13 09:01:14 ocean kernel: [39676.592040] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
   Apr 13 09:01:29 ocean kernel: [39691.764037] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
   Apr 13 09:03:19 ocean kernel: [39801.904071] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
   Apr 13 09:06:42 ocean kernel: [40004.872045] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
   Apr 13 09:13:08 ocean kernel: [    1.733757] psmouse serio1: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x0e, buttons: 3/3
   Apr 13 09:13:08 ocean kernel: [    7.193448] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 8.83.5.1 build 33692 op_mode iwldvm
   Apr 13 13:24:05 ocean kernel: [15067.014026] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 8.83.5.1 build 33692 op_mode iwldvm
   ```

   It doesn't say explicitly which firmwares needed by `iwlwifi` fail
   to load. How can I find them out, and then solve the failing-to-load problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message doesn't indicate that `iwlwifi` couldn't find a required firmware file; it indicates [that it was unable to load a chunk of firmware into the adapter](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/pcie/trans.c?v=3.19#L565). So `iwlwifi` found the firmware it was looking for, it just couldn't load (all of) it into the adapter...

Generally speaking, when looking for firmware, if you're using your distribution's kernel you should use your distribution's firmware packages; if you're using an upstream kernel you should use the [canonical firmware repository](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git).

As for your specific firmware, its version is "8.83.5.1 build 33692". The numbers in the firmware file names correspond to specific chips and API versions; so for example `iwlwifi-8000-8.ucode` is the firmware used by [`iwl-8000`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwl-8000.c?v=3.19) for 8260 and 4165 devices, with API version 8. The `iwlwifi` module lists all the different firmware files for all the chipsets it supports; since it supports lots of chipsets, it declares lots of firmware files even though it generally only needs one for any given device.

Thus `iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode` has nothing to do with `iwlwifi-8000-8.ucode`; it is used by [`iwl-7000`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwl-7000.c?v=3.19). If newer versions of the latter are published in future, you'll see an update in `linux-firmware`, but the filename will only change if the API version is increased (presumably because it changes in a backwards-incompatible fashion).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this works. It would be nice if we didn't have to assume based on the naming conventions.

Comment: @Evan what are you not sure of? What are we assuming?

Comment: In my case, I'm using Advanced-N 6205 AGN, that's in the `iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode`, so it's not evident by the name alone as there is also `iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode`, and `iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode`. See this question for more info, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/452123/3285

Comment: @Evan you’re assuming I matched the firmware by name... I pulled the names of the firmware files from the relevant source code (I’ve updated the links so they’re usable.)